# Appcelerator "finish" call leaves app still running (albeit with a black screen) in the recent apps menu

Tags: android, appcelerator

so i have a window that when i exit should cause my titanium app to shut down. However, when the app is shut down (on android, by hitting the "back" button to exit), while the app itself disappears from the screen, if i look in the list of "recent apps", I can still see it present.

If i select it from the recent apps, it will start up as if it had been properly closed (ie the splash screen will appear). The thumbnail it has in the "recent apps" is of a black, blank screen.

This is with titanium appcelerator 3.3.0, and i am using the action bar.

My main window (the first and last window of the app) looks a bit like this:

```
var learn= Ti.UI.createWindow({
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: "#EFEAE0",
    exitOnClose: true,
});
```

also, it has this:

```
windowModule.handleOpeningWindow(learn, function(){Ti.Android.currentActivity.finish();});
```

Where "windowModule" is a js class i use to handle opening and closing windows. The "function" i've added is always called when a window shuts down (ie the function is called, and then window.close() is called)

The second code sample - the code sample with the `currentActivity.finish()` was added after i noticed the issue at hand.

Is there something i'm possibly doing wrong or missing?

Comment: try ->android.os.process.killprocess(android.os.process.mypid())

Comment: "However, when the app is shut down (on android, by hitting the "back" button to exit)" -- that does not "shut down" an Android app, for any conventional definition of "shut down". "if i look in the list of "recent apps", I can still see it present" -- this is perfectly normal. All Android apps behave this way. The all-black thumbnail is unusual.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh my how interesting. The folk at the titanium api built in two "ways" to shutdown an app, either via `exitonclose` or with the `finish` method i discuss. I don't know if you are a titanium developer, but from reading your response about android apps and terminating them, the app simply should not "close" at all?

Comment: "I don't know if you are a titanium developer" -- I know of it, and I tried it a few years ago, but I am not a regular user. "the app simply should not "close" at all?" -- speaking in Android developer terms, you are welcome to `finish()` your activity. However, that does not terminate your process, nor does it remove you from the recent-tasks list. Android will clean up all of that on its own, if the user does not soon return to your app. With regards to the thumbnail on the recent-tasks list, normally that's a screenshot, and you'd have to check with Appcelerator for any problems with that.